# GoogleMap ap on Android - Creating an Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I am creating an Android application which uses GPS to show an user their current location.
I have this part of the application working and the location shows up on map view but I was wondering how do I go about adding a marker on the location? I understand it has something to do with creating an Overlay but am unsure how to go about doing this.

Also I wish for assistance in adding a zoom in/out control button.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following Link

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/03/19/tutorial-2-mapview-google-map-hit-testing-for-display-of-popup-windows/

not only you can draw anything on the map you can animate the view as well. using this i implmented drop pin effect as that of IPhone in Android

Using Canvas and onDraw Method is tough but the best and core way to handle things.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project to achieve that you want:

[mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Hope this helps.